# Add page title between PdfPTables in iText

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

I have a number of `PdfPTable`s that is following each other like this:

[image]

Is it possible to add a title on all of the page(not just the first page)? I believe I cant use the `PdfPageEventHelper` because the table that is first on each page needs to be moved down(to not overlap the title).

Any ideas or tips how this can be solved? I cant figure out how to know if there has been a new page or not for each of the tables.

```
public class TableDemo {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "first_table.pdf";

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new TableDemo().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF with tables
     * @param    filename the name of the PDF file that will be created.
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();

        document.add(addTitle());

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            document.add(createTable());

        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates our table
     * @return our table
     */
    public static PdfPTable createTable() {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

        int rows = (int)(Math.random()*30+1);
        for(int row=0; row<rows; row++){
            for(int cell=0; cell<4; cell++){
                table.addCell("row "+row+"; cell "+cell);
            }
        }

        table.setKeepTogether(true);
        table.setSpacingAfter(30);

        return table;
    }

    public static Paragraph addTitle(){
         Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 40, Font.BOLD);
         Paragraph p = new Paragraph("TITLE ON EACH PAGE", fontbold);
         p.setSpacingAfter(20);
         p.setAlignment(1); // Center
         return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a header to each page? If so, have a look at these [examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221)

Comment: Adding header is the `PdfPageEventHelper`. Problem with this is as stated, "the table that is first on each page needs to be moved down" if I make a header. And this I do not know how to achieve.

Comment: Rather than moving the content down, why don't you move the header up?

Comment: As seen in the attached image with the tables there is almost no space in the pages start. I guess I could add `table.setSpacingBefore(X);`. But this would make the space between the tables to big...

Comment: Change the margins of the document, adapt them to make the header fit.

Comment: Document magins might be able to solve the problem. Thanks